# Do entangled pair of particles share a single wave function?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, pauli-exclusion-principle

I read that Pauli exclusion principle applies to fermion and would like to know the magnitude of this consequences in nature. I used to incorrectly think that no 2 electrons in the entire universe including those uncharted and unknown region of space can share the same set of quantum numbers, but I think that if two electrons with the same quantum state will cancel out each other in an atom so what happens if two free entangled electrons separated by millions of light years apart could they have the same quantum states?

I meant do PEP apply to these entangled pair of electrons if both are separated by vast distance of space, could both the electrons share the same quantum state?[edited]

I saw a couple of videos on this topic and think half of them are exaggerated while the other are trying to induce sleep, because none seems to explain how do the particle knows if they are entangled or not.

Comment: *By definition of an entangled state* you cannot meaningfully talk about the state of individual electrons inside it. It's also not clear how your last paragraph relates to anything you said before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quantum mechanics one can represent the state for two electrons as two creation operators acting on the vacuum state

$$ a_1^{\dagger} a_2^{\dagger} |0\rangle . $$

We could just as well have written the two creation operators in the opposite order. However, fermions obey Fermi-Dirac statistics which implies that when we interchange the two operators they pick a minus sign. That is fair enough because the two expressions are not the same. However, if we have identical electrons so that
$$ a_1^{\dagger} = a_2^{\dagger} $$
then clearly the two terms should be identical and then the minus sign implies that for consistency the result has to be zero. So whenever there are more than one electorn in the universe they have to differ in some way. That leads to the Pauli exclusion principle.

Now, what if these electrons are far apart? In the expression above we use creation operators that create electrons as plane waves, which are defined everywhere in the universe. Nothing prevents us from defining our creation operators in a different basis, perhaps some set of wavelets that are more localized. In that case, the location of the basis element would serve as a quantum number. This would be enough to distinguish the electrons as being different, so that apart from the fact that these electrons are located at these different locations, all the other quantum numbers could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you were actually correct in thinking that no two electrons (fermions) can share the same quantum numbers, since this would imply that they are in *the same quantum state*, which is not allowed by the Pauli exclusion principle. So there is no "cancelling each other out" (whatever you mean by that) since such a configuration is not possible. And I am unsure of what you mean exactly in the last part of the last sentence of your query, paragraph one. And even if two free electron states are entangled, they still cannot have the same quantum states (regardless of how far apart they are). The term *entangled state* implies that there is no properly defined notion of the states of each of these electrons. Can you try to rephrase your question?

Comment: Working on it..

Answer (score -1):

Let me paraphrase. No two electrons can be in the same quantum state. Separated quantum systems with no casual connection or correlation can have the same quantum numbers, but when talking about the PEP we mean states in the same *quantum system*.